# ubuntu auto redirect to file when the name matched? $1 contains something.php but not something

Tags: php, .htaccess, ubuntu

I am working on UBUNTU 12,04. Here is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$  something.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The problem is when I type in localhost/something for the request,the request become something.php automatically if the file does exist. But it works fine in Windows when I type in localhost/something $1 still equal to something. Is there anyway to disable this setting?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Can you clarify what exactly is happening in Ubuntu and what's happening in Windows? The request becomes something.php if which file exists?

Comment: Let me clarify my problem. In windows with the htaccess code I gave when I type in http://localhost/something in the browser, $1 will return "something"(the thing that I typed in). But in linux $1 become something.php if there is a php file in the direstory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like Apache's [MultiViews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html#multiviews) feature is enabled.

`Options -MultiViews` in that same .htaccess will disable it for that directory.

Alternatively, you can remove `MultiViews` from the `Options` directive that probably exists for your document root in your httpd.conf and to disable this server- or host-wide.